# how to develop msf4j-apps and deploy them in wso2ei

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator, msf4j, wso2-msf4j

the about-page of wso2ei 6.1.1 (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/About+this+Release) 
mentioned the possibility to develop and especially to deploy msf4j apps in wso2ei:

> From WSO2 EI 6.1.0 onwards, it does not ship the functionalities of
>   WSO2 Application Server (AS). **However, you can develop applications
>   using MSF4J, JAX-RS or JAX-WS technologies and deploy in WSO2 EI**. If
>   you already have applications in WAR or AAR formats, use WSO2 AS 5.3.0
>   or Tomcat as the server to deploy web apps. Nevertheless, WSO2 still
>   provides complete development and production support for WSO2 AS.

I am very interested to do this, but unfortunally I can not find any information on this topic. I would be happy to receive information and links to this topic.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough. Service development and deployment is as you described it feasable. I want to develop especially msf4j-applications what should be possible regarding the quoted test. With newer versions than 6.0.0 for wso2ei the applicationserver is not longer a part of it, so it is not obviously how to deploy applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop a service using MSF4J and deployed it with the MSF4J profile which is available with the WSO2 EI. Sample is mentioned in [Doc 1](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/Exposing+Several+Services+as+a+Single+Service)

Highlevel steps would be

1. Develop the MSF4J service
2. Put that jar file in `<EI_HOME>/wso2/msf4j/deployment` directory
3. Start the MSF4J profile in EI  `<EI_HOME>/wso2/msf4j/bin/carbon.sh`

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear enough. Service development and deployment is as you described it feasable. I want to develop especially msf4j-applications what should be possible regarding the quoted test. With newer versions than 6.0.0 for wso2ei the applicationserver is not longer a part of it, so it is not obviously how to deploy applications.

Comment: You can have a look at MSF4J samples available in https://github.com/wso2/msf4j/tree/master/samples and get familiar. It is plain Jax RS with some MSF4J specific stuffs